# import fails but local declaration to the file works

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs, prisma

I am using Prisma and typescript, I have a file containing a prismaClient named
`client.ts` where I export prismaClient such that i can use it my test.

```
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'

const prismaClient = new PrismaClient()

export default prismaClient
```

I then import the client in my test file and use it like this

```
//some imports here
import prismaClient from './../../../client'  <==== Import

test("email not confirmed", async () => {
  // logic

  const user = await prismaClient.user.update({
    where: {
      email: email
    },
    data: {
      confirmed: true,
    }
  });

  console.log(user);

  // logic

}, 30000);
```

Now this doesn't work because the user is not updated, however when I declare the prismaClient local to this file like this

```
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'
const prismaClient = new PrismaClient()  <===================Local

test("email not confirmed", async () => {
  // logic

  const user = await prismaClient.user.update({
    where: {
      email: email
    },
    data: {
      confirmed: true,
    }
  });

  console.log(user);

  // logic

}, 30000);
```

everything works(user gets updated), this gets me to think that there's a way local declarations can behave different from imports. Someone could help me explain.

Comment: what error was returned?

Comment: no error, the test was just failing

Comment: Can you add the path of the prismaClient.ts & testFile

Comment: What happens when you catch on the update() and log the error?

Comment: @kevintechie it's undefined

Comment: That's strange. It's throwing an error, but the error is undefined? Can you show your code?

Comment: @kevintechie i get ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'catch' of undefined``` when I do a catch

Comment: what's mostly confusing me is why the imported version of prismaClient doesnt work

Comment: My guess is that either there is a problem with the import path or the prisma client goes out of scope. You don't show enough of your project for us to duplicate your results.